# generating all permuated products from a map is not working

Tags: c++, recursion

My code:

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    using ll = long long;
    vector<ll> generate_all(map<ll, int> mp, int keys_done, ll prod) {
      if (keys_done == mp.size()) {
        vector<ll> v;
        v.push_back(prod);
        return v;
      }
      vector<ll> vr;
      int ctr = 0;
      for (auto it = mp.begin(); it != mp.end(); ++it, ctr++) {
        if (ctr < keys_done or ctr > keys_done)
          continue;
        ll next_prod = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j <= it->second; j++) {
          next_prod *= it->first;
          vector<ll> v1 = generate_all(mp, 1 + keys_done, prod * next_prod);
          for (int k = 0; k < v1.size(); k++) {
            vr.push_back(v1[k]);
          }
        }
      }
      return vr;
    }
    int main() { 
        map<ll, int> mp = {{2,4},{3,1}, {5,3}}; 
        vector<ll> v_final=generate_all(mp,0,1); 
        for (const auto & val:v_final) { 
               cout << val << endl; 
        } 
    }
```

current output:

`2`

Expected output

```
 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 20, 24, 25, 30, 40, 48, 50, 60, 75, 80, 100, 120, 125, 150, 200, 240, 250, 300, 375, 400, 500, 600, 750, 1000, 1200, 1500, 2000, 3000, 6000
```

To illustrate the output it is the following:

```
    2^1,2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 3^1, 5^1, 5^2, 5^3, 
    2^1 * 3, 2^2 * 3, 2^3 * 3, 2^4 * 3, 5^1 * 3, 5^2 * 3, 5^3 * 3, 
    2^1 * 5, 2^2 * 5, 2^3 * 5, 2^4 * 5, 
    2^1 * 5^2, 2^2 * 5^2, 2^3 * 5^2, 2^4 * 5^2, 3^1 * 5^2, 
    2^1 * 5^3, 2^2 * 5^3, 2^3 * 5^3, 2^4 * 5^3, 3^1 * 5^3, 
    2^1 * 3^1 * 5^1, 2^1 * 3^1 * 5^2, 2^1 * 3^1 * 5^3, 
    2^2 * 3^1 * 5^1, 2^2 * 3^1 * 5^2, 2^2 * 3^1 * 5^3, 
    2^3 * 3^1 * 5^1, 2^3 * 3^1 * 5^2, 2^3 * 3^1 * 5^3, 
    2^4 * 3^1 * 5^1, 2^4 * 3^1 * 5^2, 2^4 * 3^1 * 5^3,
```

Here `2` can have 0 to 4 th power multiplied by `3` from 0 to 4 th power and so on.
If the choices were limited to 3 like this example. this is how my code would have looked:

```
vector<ll>v;

for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<=1;j++)
    for(int k=0;k<=3;k++)
      v.insert(pow(2,i)*pow(3,j)*pow(5,k));
return v;
```

But I need to solve for k such keys not just 3 keys.

If possible do also suggest a non-recusrvice method.

Comment: `using ll = long long;` nice to see bad ideas being updated to take advantage of new features. Significantly less destructive than the old `#define ll long long`

Comment: Is that the sole reason for wrong output? if so then I am happy to revert to `#define` immediately. Can we focus on the core logic and its impementation first. for the sake of  avoiding distaction on stackoverflow let me make all my `ll` to `int`

Comment: No. That has no impact on anything but the readability of the code. I'm just impressed that people hacking out quicky code like this bothered to update a stock macro with something a lot less likely to cause additional pain.

Comment: I am not just looking to fix the bug but also find get a cleaner implementation if possible without a recursion. Very difficult to find c++ experts on stackoverflow, now that I have managed to engage with someone like you, I dont want to let the opportunity go by discussing macros etc.

Comment: To improve the question and be more likely to attract an answer: Provide a complete program, fill out a `main` that inputs the test values and prints the results. Something stupid and simple like `int main() { map<ll, int> mp = {{2,4},{3,1}, {5,3}}; vector<ll> v_final=generate_all(mp,0,1); for (const auto & val:v_final) { cout << val << endl; } }` should do the trick there. Also add the results of your debugging runs, what you've noticed about where the program deviates from your expectations.

Comment: Ask only one thing at a time. Either "Help me find and fix the bug" or "How do I do this iteratively?" Ask both and the question runs a risk of being closed for lacking focus.

Comment: I don't understand what the rule for the expected output is supposed to be. Add an explanation and a simpler example please. This can be very likely solved in a simpler and cleaner way using standard library algorithms.

Comment: @user17732522 the part I am strugggling is how to pick and chose which subset in next_permutation. Here as you can see the the permutation can have any length. Do you mean I should start with a initial array like this `[2,2,2,2,3,5,5,5]` or `[2,4,8,16,3,5,25,125]` .Mind you the keys can me more its not fixed like hereit is only `2,3,5`

Comment: @rosefoster I edited my comment. Now I am not sure where permutations are used at all. It looks to me like you want to generate all numbers with (prime) factor decompositions which have multiplicities at most equal to the values in the map. I don't know for sure whether this is what you want since you don't give any explanation of the output and even with that assumption I don't know whether you want the output in a particular order and whether duplicates matter to you.

Comment: @user17732522 Given prime factors of a number in key value format (where value indicates the frequency of a prime) I have to generate all the factors.Order is not important.

Comment: @user17732522 For ease of understanding I added the code for this special case at the bottom. I need to solve for general case with k primes.

Comment: @rosefoster I suggest you run the test program in a debugger step-by-step to see where it doesn't behave in the way you intend it to. This should allow you to find the logic mistake. There is no standard library function that really simplifies this task I think. However, the output I currently get from your code is different than the one you claim. The address sanitizer didn't give any diagnostic, so I guess there are no out-of-bound accesses or anything like that. Probably there is just a logic error in the algorithm. (https://godbolt.org/z/EG5895qKc)

Comment: There is a java [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644903/19104530) on stackoverflow. As of now I am using that. That works fine. But still has a recursion, hoping someone can do it in few lines using `next_permutation`. in python actually this can be very efficiently done in few lines without recursion.

Answer (score 1):

We have to implement 2 major mathematical concepts here

1. Create a power set
2. Building the cartesian product over several sets (or the comnination of all elements over several sets)

The task contains some additional indirections to add a little bit complexity.

Let's start with the power set.

We will first make a simplification for an easier understanding of the task. We will name the input pairs, consisting of a base value and an exponent, as set elements a,b,c and so on. If we assume an input of  `{ {2,4},{3,1}, {5,3}, {4,2} }`, then we will name this now as a set with 4 elements `{a,b,c,d}`.

What we need to generate is a power set from this. There are 2 main standard approaches.

1. Counting with checking of set bits via it mask
2. Setting more and more bits in a field and do permutations.

Let us look at solution 1. Counting. Based on "abcd" we will get

```
Count Binary Selection (sub set)
              DCBA   Cardinality
0     0000   {----}     0                Empty set
1     0001   {---A}     1
2     0010   {--B-}     1
3     0011   {--BA}     2
4     0100   {-C--}     1
5     0101   {-C-A}     2
6     0110   {-CB-}     2
7     0111   {-CBA}     3     
8     1000   {D---}     4
9     1001   {D--A}     2
10    1010   {D-B-}     2
11    1011   {D-BA}     3
12    1100   {DC--}     3
13    1101   {DC-A}     3
14    1110   {DCB-}     3
15    1111   {DCBA}     4

As a result we will get the powerset:
{{A},{B},{AB},{C},{AC},{BC},{ABC},{D},{AD},{BD},{ABD},{CD},{ACD},{BCD},{ABCD}}
```

If you look at the output, we see that the elements are not sorted according to their cardinality. Therefore we will choose a different approach. We will set more and more bits in a field an do permutations on them. Also with a selector. Then, we will get something like this:

```
Binary  Selection
0000      {----}                    Empty set. Ignored
0001      {---A}                    Set bit 0
0010      {--B-}                    Permutation
0101      {-C--}                    Permutation
1000      {D---}                    Permutation
0011      {--BA}                    Set next bit number 1
0101      {-C-A}                    Permutation      
1001      {D--A}                    Permutation      
0110      {-CB-}                    Permutation      
1010      {D-B-}                    Permutation      
1100      {D--A}                    Permutation      
0111      {-CBA}                    Set next bit number 2
1011      {D-BA}                    Permutation      
1101      {DC-A}                    Permutation      
1110      {DCB-}                    Permutation      
1111      {DCBA}                    Set next bit number 3

As a result we will get the "more reasonable/expected" powerset:
{{A},{B},{C},{D},{AB},{AC},{AD},{BC},{BD},{AD},{ABC},{ABD},{ACD},{BCD},{ABCD}}
```

By the way. The overall number of sub sets is of course `2^n` and the size of the cardinality group is equal to the corresponding binomial coeeficient.

```
Cardinality
0    4 choose 0  --> 1   
1    4 choose 1  --> 4
2    4 choose 1  --> 6
3    4 choose 1  --> 4
4    4 choose 1  --> 1

               Sum: 16
```

The corresponding algorithm is easy to implement, which can also be seen later in the code example.

---

Next. If we have the powerset, then we need to combine all elements. Let us take as an example the sub set {ABC}. We can translate this back to the original input data:

```
{2,4},{3,1},{5,3}
```

which would expand with the given rule to

```
{2,4,8,16},{3},{5,25,125}
```

And now we need to build all combinations of that. The number of combinations is of cause the product of the cardinality of the sub sets. Here `4*1*3 = 12`. To illustrate that and get a first idea of the solution approach, we list up all combinations.

```
2  3  5
4  3  5
8  3  5
16 3  5
2  3  25
4  3  25
8  3  25
16 3  25
2  3  125
4  3  125
8  3  125
16 3  125
```

We could imagine that we have an odometer with 3 disks. Diks 1 contains 2,4,8,13, disk 2 contins 3 and disk 3 contains 5,25,125.

Everytime, when a disks rolls over than the next disk will be triggered as well. So, if the first diks is at 16 and rolls over to 2 then diks 3 is triggered. Because disk 3 contains only 1 number (the 3), it will also immediately roll over and trigger disk 3. This will then show the next value. And so on and so on.

So, we also do some sort of counting, but the counters have a different base number. Anyway. All this is easy to implement.

As an additional implementation detail, I will not use the "pow" function. I will just multiple the counter, the value on the disk, with its base value. This will save space and time. And all of this put together could be implemented like the following:

(Please note. I use "easy code". We could use many more advanced algorithms, but for the sake of readability, I go this way. As said. Many other solutions possible)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>

using MyType = unsigned long long;

// The base-number and the max exponent are the elements of a set
struct Element {
    MyType base{};
    MyType maxExponent{};

    // Actually, this elements does not store one value only, but "maxExponent" elements
    // Do get all of those, we use the well known odometer approach
    // We can always calculate the next value in the list and inform, if we have a rollover
    // In case of a roll over, we can inform other sets about this and the other set can also count up
    MyType currentResult{ base };
    MyType currentExponent{};

    // Calculate next value. So, will for {2,4} get 2, 4, 8, 16
    bool next(bool overflowFromPrevious) {

        // Indicates that we will wrap around from previous
        bool overflow{};

        // If a previous odometer roll has overflowed
        if (overflowFromPrevious) {

            // Check, if we are NOT at the end. This will happen, if ther is only 1 as the max exponent.
            if (currentExponent < maxExponent) {

                // Get next exponent
                ++currentExponent;

                // And calculate current data. We could also store those values, 
                // but we do not want to waste space
                currentResult *= base;

                // Now check again for overflow (after we incremented the exponent)
                if (currentExponent >= maxExponent) {

                    // If overlow, then reset exponent counter and base
                    currentExponent = 0;
                    currentResult = base;
                    overflow = true;
                }
            }
            else overflow = true;
        }
        return overflow;
    }
    // Simple inserter operator override, to be able to do an easier output
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Element& e) {
        return os << '{' << e.base << ',' << e.maxExponent << '}';
    }
};

// We will use a vetcor and not a set, because we need random access via the index operator
using MSet = std::vector<Element>;

void getProducts(MSet& mset) {

    // Selectors for creating the subsets of the power set
    std::vector<bool> selector(mset.size());

    // For all number of elements in the original set
    for (size_t k{}; k < mset.size(); ++k) {
        
        // Set selecot bits. In each loop one more bit. So, 1 then 11, then 111 and so on
        selector[k] = true;

        // Do all permutations of the above set bits
        do {
            // For debug output
            for (bool b : selector) std::cout << b * 1; std::cout << "  ";
            std::ostringstream oss{};       

            // Here we will store all elements of a resulting subset
            MSet subSet{};

            // Check if the selector bit is set, and if so, then add to subset
            for (size_t n{}; n < mset.size(); ++n) {
                if (selector[n]) {
                    subSet.push_back(mset[n]);

                    oss << mset[n];         // For debug output
                }
            }
            // Debug output of powerset with number of subsets
            std::cout << "Powerset("<< subSet.size()<< "): " << std::left << std::setw(22) << oss.str() << ' ';

            // Now, we want to calculate all combinations of subsets, using the odometer approach
            // Here we will store the overall number of combinations. It is the product of all max exponents
            MyType combinations{ 1 }; 
            for (const Element& element : subSet)
                combinations *= element.maxExponent;

            // Now get the product for all combinations over all subsets
            for (MyType i{}; i < combinations; ++i) {

                // Get the product for one combination
                MyType product{ 1 };
                for (Element& element : subSet)
                    product *= element.currentResult;

                std::cout << product << ' ';        // For debug output

                // And, using the odometer approach, create the next combination 
                bool overflow{true};
                for (Element& element : subSet)
                    overflow = element.next(overflow);
            }
            std::cout << '\n';                      // For debug output
        } while (std::prev_permutation(selector.begin(), selector.end()));
    }
}
// Test / driver code
int main() {
    MSet mset{ {2,4},{3,1}, {5,3}, {4,2} };

    getProducts (mset);
}
```

I added a lot of debug output. You may delete that.

With that the solution the result will be:

[image]

By the way. I think that your expected output is wrong . . .

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will add this to my library.