# Fastest way to find all the divisors of a large number

Tags: number-theory

I am facing a problem when I want to get all the divisors of a large number i.e n=10^12. There is a method, which checks all possible numbers less than square root of given number n.

```
for(int i=1; i<=sqrt(n); ++i){
    if(n%i==0){
        factors.push_back(i);
        if(i!=n/i) factors.push_back(n/i);
    }
}
```

But when n is very large i.e 10^12 then it needs 10^6 iterations which is very slow.

Is there any faster way when I have all prime divisors of given n such as given number is 48.
Then prime factorization of 720 is 2^4 * 3^2 * 5.

All the divisors of 720 are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 30, 36, 40, 45, 48, 60, 72, 80, 90, 120, 144, 180, 240, 360, 720.

I have already searched for faster way than O(sqrt(n)). But haven't found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to find all factors of a given number in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239865/best-way-to-find-all-factors-of-a-given-number-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The non-prime factors are of no interest. You should only be looking. For prime factors.

Comment: nope. I asked for large number. @EliSadoff

Comment: @Murad the algorithm is the same regardless of the size of the number.

Comment: @EJP I need all the divisors.

Comment: @EliSadoff, I haven't seen any solution on that post that works faster than O(sqrt(n)).

Comment: @Murad The best known right now is O((1/3)exp(64/9)b*log(b)^2)) which is GNFS, where `b` is the number of bits in a number `n`.

Comment: While it is faster than O(sqrt(n)) the implementation is generally very large to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Can you post the pseudo code/c++ code for this approach please?