# Number of divisors for very large number

Tags: time-complexity

Is there any fast way to find total divisors of a very large number supposedly 10^18.
I have tried a method which is of ***o(n^(1/3))***
Forgive me asking direct question without providing any background or something else.

Comment: Is your number guaranteed to be positive integers?

Comment: Have a look at this: [Fastest way to find all the divisors of a large number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939369/fastest-way-to-find-all-the-divisors-of-a-large-number)

Comment: will it be more than 12 items?

Comment: Thanks guys for helping! I was so into my problem I forgot about I have asked question. Finally I have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest algorithm for that would be [General number field sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve), probably fits your question.

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753839/efficiently-getting-all-divisors-of-a-given-number) there is some discussion ongoing about how to efficiently find all divisors. GNFS is used for factorization, so only accounts prime numbers. You'll have to derive all divisors from that, if you need to. [How to I find all divisors from prime factorization?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361609/how-to-find-all-positive-divisors-of-a-given-number)

Further reading: [A beginner's guide to the Number Field Sieve](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.219.2389&rep=rep1&type=pdf); [Factoring Integers with the Number Field Sieve](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/15590206.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I solved it using sieve of eratosthenes.