# Get list of int values in a number that was multiplied by 2

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have the number 23 which was created by the sum of numbers 16,4,2,1.
In the same way the number can be 19 (created by sum of 16,2,1)

What I am looking is to find a way to extract from which integers my number was created.
e.g for the above example of 23 I want to get back an array of 16,4,2,1.

How can I do that using c#?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to find all factors of a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239865/best-way-to-find-all-factors-of-a-given-number)

Comment: what did you try? Shouldn´t be that difficult to iterate your numbers and devide by two, is it?

Comment: 23 is {16,4,2,1}, Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of (non-negative) base-2, this is simply: "which binary bits are set?"

So:

```cs
int value = ... // 23, for example
int bit = 1;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 31 ; i++)
{
    if ((bit & value) != 0)
    {
        // add "bit"
        Console.WriteLine(bit); // just to show
    }
    bit <<= 1;
}
```